# Objects on other pages keep moving

Tags: visio

I'm new to Visio so I apologize if this is obvious.

I have a Visio doc with a background page and a few other pages with a lot of objects on them.

For some reason, when I move things as a group on one page, objects on other pages also move. This only seems to happen when moving objects as a group.

Also, my background page seems to move in the opposite direction of where I moved the group of objects. For example, if I move the objects to the left, when I look back at my background page everything has moved to the right.

Can anyone tell me what's causing this? I thought I understood how Visio worked until this started happening and I'm at a loss as to how to prevent it.

Answer (score 0):

I think I've figured it out.

The grid (I think that's the right term) was not the same size on all of my pages, and some pages had the grid start/end at different coordinates.

Once I made sure all of my grids started at 0,0 and were the same size, things started behaving the way I wanted them to.

It was really simple, but I didn't think about it until now.